# Can mod_jk disable/stop forwarding request to an tomcat instance which is not responding?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, load-balancing, tomcat6, mod-jk

I integrated Apache mod_jk with 4 Tomcat servers. After some time if
any Tomcat in a hanging state new requests are going to that Tomcat (I think this is a normal behavior of mod_jk).

Is there any way to stop requests going to
a Tomcat server which is hanging/not responding state ?

Comment: Indeed it can, and it does. See the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/common_howto/timeouts.html).

Comment: thanks EJP. i got it

Answer (score 1):

For best results, I'd recommend configuring cping/cpong appropriately for your environment. You might not need the connection-check for every single request, but it's an option.

Read about cping/cpong on the [workers configuration reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html) looking for the `ping_mode` worker directive.

It's *disabled* by default, so you have to explicitly enable it. For the most-robust service, you'd need to set this to `A` to enable all checks. If it seems to be slowing things down, consider backing-off to a setting of `I`.